What does "sweeping classical music" mean?
I'm watching the Johny Depp/Amber Heard trial documentary on Netflix and there is a musical composition worked into the footage of a cityscape when a narrator talks about the penthouses he owned and the subtitle for it says ["sweeping classical music"]. I don't know what "sweeping" means in this context. No definition for it fits the context so I provided something that fits least bad.
move swiftly and smoothly.
"a large black car swept past the open windows"

The phrase puts me in mind of Mickey Mouse and the enchanted brooms in Sorceror's Apprentice from Disney's Fantasia.

I would say the closest synonym here is "expansive". (Collins entry)
Music described as sweeping is expansive, large, epic. Such an effect might be achieved by a large orchestra producing a lot of sound, with great motion and feeling.
